# JWPlayer (new version) throws an error and doesn't play on the site

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using latest version of JWPlayer and it shows a blank space when open the page with the video. The weird part is that when I refresh it twice/thrice, it works fine.

But it almost never works the first time the page opens.

This the error it shows in the console :-

```
Error handling "jwplayerReady" event listener [0]: SyntaxError: Failed to execute
'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule  '#5831ef82aa5f92337bd88fe0c8d54bec_display_button  { background-image:
 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAA0CAYAAACHO2h8AAAA7ElEQ…
8thSpN0xvbts0lxeZb/ACrDeOgYYyVOWeinyp6gnWdW0Vft69cndg2ea8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=), 
url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAA0CAYAAACQGfi1AAAAZUlEQ…
v6Y0rIAygi5D8UjUUjA/aAyZwwOPIP2mMKRd9bdM79KAVee0AqrmZ58iQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=), 
url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAA0CAYAAACHO2h8AAAA8klEQ…
ZFjXwb55x8WtyKGtGRUpZCcLR7dzJ+B0iSy03DisYEQo0nc8B4p9SUlywAAAAASUVORK5CYII=); 
background-position: left,center,right; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
 height: 52px; margin-top: -26px; }'. function (b){l.playerReady(b);a.css.unblock(d.id)}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: Could you check the source in the console before passing it to jwplayer setup, check if the source is working correctly. Also, it would be helpful if you provide any link or jwplayer setup code which you are using to run this

Comment: Also check the answer evilom gave and check if your container div ID starts with a numerical character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it happens when my container div ID starts with a numerical character.

```
jwplayer("2someID").setup({
        file: fileURL,
        image: imgURL
    });
```

see my example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msvillanueva/VvKmx/)

try changing the div container id with a non-numeric character.

Check this [link](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/naming-ids-with-numbers/) for more information

Comment: evilom : great observation (y) !!! i would like to know how did you find this might be cause of error

Comment: I am adding one helpful link : http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/naming-ids-with-numbers/ in your answer

Comment: hitesh: Thanks! I am using multiple JW instances on a single page with randomly generated div IDs. Some of my IDs starts with a number and these divs causes the error when binding JW to them.