# JWPlayer in Drupal has container ID starting with Numeric Character

Tags: html, drupal-7, jwplayer

Following up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499767/jw-player-new-version-throws-an-error-and-doesnt-play-on-the-site) on SO, I am looking to change the default DIV container name that JWplayer provides to JWPlayer Div. The problem is that it starts with a numeric and that creates loading problems.

Is there a way, I can customize this JWPlayer ID ?

This is how it looks btw,

```
jwplayer('141ef7fe77391234fc105767808cc0a5').setup({"file":"my_video.mp4",
      "width":"838","height":"383","controlbar":"none",
      "modes":[{"type":"html5"},{"type":"flash","src":"http://path/jwplayer/player.swf"}]});
```

Comment: Where are you running this?

Comment: What Ethan really means is, "Please give us a link to your site." Telling us you're running this "on my Drupal site" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're at it, here is a quick solution to it.

Since this is a fix for Drupal JWPlayer Module, do the following:-

- Go to `jw_player` module folder and open `theme` folder.
- Open `jw_player.tpl.php` and add the following line on top (probably where PHP declaration starts).

> ```
> $html_id = "myvideo". $html_id;
> ```

It kinda does the job but I am sure you guys have better solutions than this. Please feel free to comment.

### Found a better solution

Don't do upper suggestion. Paste the following code in `jw_player.module` instead.

Find this line `$variables['html_id'] = md5(rand());` (I guess line 308) and uncomment it before pasting the following code instead.

```
while(1) {

      $variables['html_id'] = md5(rand());
      if (ctype_alpha(substr($variables['html_id'], 0, 1))) {
        //echo "First Digit is Alphabet";
        break;
      }

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, great, glad you got it!

Comment: Both solution are terrible. You suggest hacking the JW Player module. Any changes will be reverted when the module is updated. Latest version of the module don't use `md5(rand()` as `html_id` so I assume the problem is now fixed.

Comment: Do you have a better solution? If yes, please post it here. We all would love to know